# How to parse this string to extract email addresses?

Tags: java, parsing

I'm getting list of email addresses in a servlet as a parameter in from request in following format:

```
,Group 4: [abc@xyz.com,asd@dsa.com],,Group 4: [abc@xyz.com],,Group 3: [],,Group 2:
[qwe@rty.com,yui@gui.com,jih@app.com,abc@xyz.com,asd@dsa.com],,Group 1: 
[pick@pick.com,test@pick.com,test1@pick1.com],,Nirmal testGroup: [qwe@rty.com],
```

How can I parse all unique email addresses from this in Java?

Group names are not important. Also it is not necessary that a group name will be always as Group 1, Group 3, it can be anything containing spaces. Just need to have list/array of all unique email addresses from the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to pick out everything between square brackets (`[]`), then [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) each of those on the commas:

```
String example = ",Group 4: [abc@xyz.com,asd@dsa.com],,Group 4: [abc@xyz.com],,Group 3: [],,Group 2:\n" +
                         "[qwe@rty.com,yui@gui.com,jih@app.com,abc@xyz.com,asd@dsa.com],,Group 1: \n" +
                         "[pick@pick.com,test@pick.com,test1@pick1.com],,Nirmal testGroup: [qwe@rty.com],";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
while (matcher.find()) {
    for (String email : matcher.group(1).split(",")) {
        System.out.println(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help in building regex as I don't have used any regex before so have no idea in how to do it?

Comment: What about uniqueness? I mean email id should be unique. should I use use a HashSet and save all id in it. Does this ensure uniqueness?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good approach. Note also that my code doesn't filter out empty results either.

Comment: Yes I have figured out. Just added a condition before adding id to Set like `if(email.trim().length()>0)`.

Comment: Are you sure email addressed can't contain `[` or `]`?