# How to extract email addresses from a list?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse/trim email addresses from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098581/how-to-parse-trim-email-addresses-from-text)

How can I extract email address from a list of names and email addresses?

Example input:

```
"a1 b.d"<a1@test.com>,
<a2@test.com>,
"a3 b.d"<a3@test.com> ,
a4@test.com ,
```

Output :

```
a1@test.com,
a2@test.com,
a3@test.com,
a4@test.com,
```

Comment: Try some sort of regex i.e : `string.replace(/"[^"]+"/g, '').replace(/(\<|\>)/g, '');`

Answer (score 0):

```
function extract_emails_from($string) {
         preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $string, $matches);
         return $matches[0];
}
```

Thinks Following this URL will help you.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/extract-email-addresses/

Answer (score 0):

This PHP function will extract an email address from a string and put it into a clickable link:

```
function extractEmail( $data )
{
    if ( preg_match( "/[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}/i", $data, $email ) )
    {
        $replacement = '<a href="mailto:' . $email[ 0 ] . '" target="_blank">' . $email[ 0 ] . '</a> ';
        $data        = preg_replace( "/[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}/i", $replacement, $data );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

To use it create PHP file and add there a test entry (but not forget to place the function above in it):

```
<?php
  echo extractEmail("Some text goes here before mail@mail.com and some text here goes after");
?>
```